# Excel Web Access print button is disabled

Tags: excel, excel-services

The print button in the excel sheet that I have uploaded to a powerpivot gallery is not enabled. How do I enable it?

> File > Print  show a print friendly view

According to this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326212.aspx)

> If you have an Actions menu but Print is not on it, the print functionality has been disabled on the report server and you cannot use it.

how do I enable it on the report server?